# Number of nonzero intersections with translated sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have two finite sets $A,B\subset\mathbb Z$. I am interested in an upper bound on the number of translations of $B$ by integers that have nonzero intersections with $A$ i.e. $$T(A,B):=\lvert\{k\in\mathbb Z~|~A\cap(B+k)\not=\emptyset\}\lvert.$$

One obviously has $T(A,B)\leq\text{diam}(A)+\text{diam}(B)-1$ where diam denotes the diameter of a set. I was wondering: What is a good bound on $T(A,B)$ in terms of $\lvert A\lvert$ and $\lvert B\lvert$?

Comment: If $B$ is a tight cluster and $A$ is very spread out, we get $|A||B|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that $T(A,B)\le |A||B|$.

And this upper bound is achievable. Let $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,b\}$. Let $A$ be a set of $a$ elements such that the distance between any two elements of $A$ is greater than $b$. Then $T(A,B)=ab$.